# Upgrade to Rails 6 causes SQLite dependency error on CentOS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-6

We recently upgraded to Rails 6 and am seeing the following SQLite error when trying to migrate the database or run tests

```
rails aborted!
Your version of SQLite (3.7.17) is too old. Active Record supports SQLite >= 3.8.
```

I tried doing a `yum update`to update the SQLite drivers etc, but the version of SQLite remained the same at `3.7.17`.

How can I upgrade the SQLite packages to make this work with Rails 6?

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, the latest version of SQLite packages available in yum is `3.7.17`. You will need to download the latest SQLite RPM's manually and `yum install` them yourself.

```
wget https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org//packages/sqlite/3.8.11/1.fc21/x86_64/sqlite-devel-3.8.11-1.fc21.x86_64.rpm
wget https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org//packages/sqlite/3.8.11/1.fc21/x86_64/sqlite-3.8.11-1.fc21.x86_64.rpm

yum install sqlite-3.8.11-1.fc21.x86_64.rpm sqlite-devel-3.8.11-1.fc21.x86_64.rpm
```

Then you can verify the installed sqlite version with:

```
sqlite3 --version
```

Answer (score -1):

wget https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org/packages/sqlite/3.9.0/1.fc21/x86_64/sqlite-devel-3.9.0-1.fc21.x86_64.rpm

wget https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org/packages/sqlite/3.9.0/1.fc21/x86_64/sqlite-3.9.0-1.fc21.x86_64.rpm

yum install sqlite-3.9.0-1.fc21.x86_64.rpm  sqlite-devel-3.9.0-1.fc21.x86_64.rpm

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.